# how to add Title (linked to item with edit menu) in content query webpart

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have added content query webpart to a page. In webpart properties -> query field-> additional filters, I am able to see only title field in the dropdown. However I want to add Title (linked to item with edit menu), so that edit menu comes with the items. Please suggest how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a view or maybe modify your existing view and there you'll be able to choose Title Column[image]

and on webpart properties you'll just choose the right view that you created/modified

Comment: I will be happy if you could mark my solution as an answer ... if my solution helped you

Comment: Thanks Melad for your prompt reply. In my view I already have that column 'Title (linked to edit menu)'. However, I am not able to choose that view in content query webpart. How to choose the view ?